# Does MX record conflict with A record?

Tags: domain-name-system, email

I am pretty new to networking.
I would like to buy a domain to setup a website and to use it also for emails.
To do this, I should need to configure an A DNS record and a MX one.
My question is... If I use a different server for emails than the one I use for the website (let's say I decide to use gmail with the custom domain), will email be sent ONLY to the server set up with the MX record, or will they also be sent to the A one? I'm asking because I saw a lot of configurations using a subdomain for emails, like "mail.domain.com", and therefore there is no risk of conflicting IP resolutions.
I basically don't want that also the VPS provider receive the emails, as I want them to be handled only by Google

Comment: This already have answers here: https://serverfault.com/q/1015231/274176

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Point A and MX records to different servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/1015231/point-a-and-mx-records-to-different-servers)

Answer (score 3):

Mail will always be sent to the MX records that are configured for a domain<sup>1</sup>.

It is perfectly suitable to set up a domain with the `A` record for the bare domain and `www` pointing towards a web server and the MX record(s) to a different provider.

```
example.com.     IN A 10.9.8.7
www.example.com. IN A 10.9.8.7
example.com.     IN MX 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
example.com.     IN MX 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
```

---

Note 1:  <sub>there are a couple of possible exceptions/corner cases, for instance when you name name your own VPS `example.com` and attempt to send mail from that VPS to `tuscirlio@example.com` odds are that  the mail daemon on that VPS will say: *'"hey, *`@example.com`* , that's me!"* and attempt local delivery rather than looking up the MX record and sending the message to G suite.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The 'A' and 'MX' records are orthogonal concepts. The MX record outlines where email should go, the A record to which IP address a particular DNS entry resolves to. The simplest example would be something like;

- MX record for your fqdn (mydomain.com), pointing to mail.mydomain.com.
- A record for mail.mydomain.com pointing to a given IP address.

You mention you're looking to configure email to be delivered to gmail. It is not clear whether you're planning to use a mailserver operated by Google (hosted email for your domain), or whether you're looking to forward email from your domain to a specific emailbox (e.g. myemail@gmail.com). In the latter case, you´ll probably need to configure a mailserver that provides that forward.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use a different server for emails than the one I use for the
> website (let's say I decide to use gmail with the custom domain), will
> email be sent ONLY to the server set up with the MX record, or will
> they also be sent to the A one?

The answer is yes but. You will be interested about [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), more specifically section 5.1. An SMTP client *may* use A records as **fallback** mechanism if no MX is found. Keep in mind that not all systems will necessarily do that or follow RFCs strictly.

> 5.1.  Locating the Target Host
>
> Once an SMTP client lexically identifies a domain to which mail will
> be delivered for processing (as described in Sections 2.3.5 and 3.6),
> a DNS lookup MUST be performed to resolve the domain name (RFC 1035 ).
> The names are expected to be fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs):
> mechanisms for inferring FQDNs from partial names or local aliases are
> outside of this specification.  Due to a history of problems, SMTP
> servers used for initial submission of messages SHOULD NOT make such
> inferences (Message Submission Servers [18] have somewhat more
> flexibility) and intermediate (relay) SMTP servers MUST NOT make them.
>
> The lookup first attempts to locate an MX record associated with the
> name.  If a CNAME record is found, the resulting name is processed as
> if it were the initial name.  If a non-existent domain error is
> returned, this situation MUST be reported as an error.  If a temporary
> error is returned, the message MUST be queued and retried later (see
> Section 4.5.4.1).  **If an empty list of MXs is returned, the address
> is treated as if it was associated with an implicit MX RR, with a
> preference of 0, pointing to that host.**  If MX records are present,
> but none of them are usable, or the implicit MX is unusable, this
> situation MUST be reported as an error.

[Source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5.1)

Transient DNS resolutions errors can and do occur. So there is a possibility that the host of the A record(s) will receive incoming mail. It is your responsibility to properly configure your zone but if you have an MTA running on the A address and assuming you can't disable it you should ensure that it will **not** accept mail for your domain name. The exact configuration depends on the software.

Comment: The fallback doesn't apply if there is an MX record, as there would be with this configuration. There's no really such error condition where A would be resolved but MX for the same hostname not.